# Taxonomy access denied

Tags: 2013, development, taxonomy

Trying to access the Taxonomy in a SP 2013 solution (VS2012, C#), but always get a access denied (unauthorized access) on the TaxonomySession object if I am logged in as a "normal" user. If I am logged in as an termstore administrator everything works fine.

I even tried to clear the httpContext (http://www.communardo.de/home/techblog/2011/10/18/sharepoint-2010-der-termstore-und-der-priviligierte-nutzer/), but no success. The SPSite object for the TaxonomySession is even created as the SystemAccount.

All I need is read access for the solution.... cant't get it, what am I doing wrong?

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite thisSite = new SPSite(guid, SPUserToken.SystemAccount))
            {
                try
                {                        
                    TaxonomySession taxonomySession = new TaxonomySession(thisSite, true);                        
                    TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.DefaultKeywordsTermStore;

                    Group navGroup = termStore.Groups[group];
                    TermSet termSet = navGroup.TermSets[termset];

                    _termset = termSet;
                    termCollection = termSet.Terms;
                    _termCollection = termCollection;

                    NavigationTermSet navigationTermSet = NavigationTermSet.GetAsResolvedByWeb(termSet, thisSite.RootWeb, StandardNavigationProviderNames.GlobalNavigationTaxonomyProvider);
                    _navigationTermSet = navigationTermSet;

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }//try

            }//using            
        });//SPSecurity
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the Application Pool account as term Store administrator.[image]

For check your application pool account´s use the following command:

**Get-SPServiceApplicationPool**

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this did not fix my problem. Still getting an unauthorized message...